# Lowest Common Multiple / Aggregation of Weights

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have to assign weights to 58 individual performance indicators, to get the following outcome:

```
Group A has 22 indicators and must account for 35% of the total weights.
Group B has 4 indicators and must account for 10% of the total weights.
Group C has 29 indicators and must account for 35% of the total weights.
Group D has 3 indicators and must account for 20% of the total weights.
```

The indicators within each group must have the same weight, and the weightings must be integers.

Can anyone help me work this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the total weight be $22\times29\times3\times20=38280$. $35$ percent of $38280$ is $7\times22\times29\times3$, so each $A$-indicator should have weight $7\times29\times3$.

$10$ percent of $38280$ is $22\times29\times3\times2$, so each $B$-indicator has weight $11\times29\times3$.

And so on.

Comment: Sorry, where do you get the `20` from, in `22 x 29 x 3 x 20`? Should that have been `4`? I'm also not sure where `7 x 22 x 29 x 3` comes from?

Comment: $35$ percent is $7/20$, so I need a $20$ so when I take $35$ I'll have a whole number. What do you get when you take $35$ percent of $22\times29\times3\times20$? that is, when you multiply $22\times29\times3\times20$ by $7/20$?

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why you used `22 x 29 x 3`? ie. Why not `22 x 29 x 3 x 4`?

Comment: Why don't you try using $22\times29\times3\times4$, and see what happens?

Comment: I'm trying to understand your reasoning/logic. With 22 & 29 & 3 - you've used 3 of the 4 grouped indicator counts. I don't understand why you didn't use the fourth one, i.e. 4. I get the 20 too: a number you can use for the percentages to get whole numbers. I see that your solution works, I'm trying to understand it though.

Comment: If you had done as I suggested and tried using $22\times29\times3\times4$, you would have found that it works, but it gives weightings that are all multiples of $4$. So we don't need the $4$ to get integer weightings, so I didn't use it.